# Problem installing patterns & practices SharePoint Guidance

Tags: 2007, guidance, patterns-and-practices

I'm having trouble setting up the Partner Portal. I got a System.NotImplementedException when I ran the setup script. Can someone shine some light on this?

I am running VSeWSS using the local machine administrator account.

```
18:05:14.24
call 02_CreateContosoServices.bat

************************************
18:05:24.06
call 03a_BuildSolutions.bat

************************************
18:05:37.51
call 03b_PackageSolutions.bat

2010/01/03 17:45:27    Error
Error: System.NotImplementedException
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at EnvDTE.Project.get_CodeModel()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.GetTypesAsCodeElement(Project project, CodeElement parent, String targetTypeFullName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Reflection.TypeFinder.Find(Project project, String targetTypeFullName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.FindClasses(Project project)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.GetClassMap(Project project)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureElementDirector.Constract()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.GetFeatureElement(ICollection`1 directors)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceFeatureDirector.Constract()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.ConstractElements()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SourceSolutionDirector.Constract()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.CreateCore(ISPProject project, IDirectorCreator creator)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.SharePointSolutions.SolutionCreator.Create(ISPProject project)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Tools.Forms.SPToolWindow.CreateSolutions()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check the system requirements which are listed in the readme.txt delivered in the spg? I've got the same error. It was fixed by installing:
 Windows SharePoint Services 3.0: Software Development Kit (SDK)
Also check the version of the Silverlight SDK. Should be 2 and not 3 !

Kind regards,
Andre

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem. In our case it was due to a different version of VSeWSS being used to create the project than was currently installed on the machine.